# CGFloat value from frame.height

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgfloat

I got stuck with something very stupid: cannot operate with CGFloat getting from view size. Could somebody help me and explain what am I doing wrong:

Here is the code:

```
 CGFloat containedViewHeight = self.containedView_.frame.size.height;
 NSLog(@"========================   containedViewHeight  ================= %d", containedViewHeight);
 NSLog(@"========================   containedViewHeight1  ================= %d", self.containedView_.frame.size.height);
```

Here what I got:

```
 ========================   containedViewHeight  ================= 1587588653

 ========================   containedViewHeight1  ================= 775
```

Value "775" looks good, but I cant save it to any variable.
I also tried something like this:

```
int offset = containerHeight - (int)(self.containedView_.frame.size.height);
```

> (int)(self.containedView_.frame.size.height) is always equal 0

Please give me a hint of what is wrong...

*** If I use %f as inside log than I got:

```
========================   containedViewHeight  ================= 0.000000
=======================   containedViewHeight1  ================= 0.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `%d` to NSLog's string format. That interprets `containedViewHeight` as an integer. You want `%f`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it does not work eather:

Comment: ==================   containedViewHeight  ================= 0.000000
=================   containedViewHeight1  ================= 0.000000

Comment: Then I expect that `self.containedView_.frame.size.height` is zero. Why do you believe it's something else?

Comment: Because the view exists on the screen and I also got another values printed using %d

Comment: It existing on screen doesn't mean that *this variable* has the frame you expect at the time you're reading it. It may be resized at a different time, or the view on screen may be a different object. Using `%d` doesn't tell you anything, because it's incorrectly decoding the memory. It doesn't mean "convert this to an int." It means "read this raw memory, and I promise you it is an int." You can double-check this with a debugger. I expect the value is 0.